# Is it possible to find out which upstream DNS server my router is querying? (just using dns tools)

Tags: dns, isp, dig

Ok, here is the setup:
I have a local router which advertises itself as the DNS server over DHCP. The DNS resolver on the router just forwards the requests to the ISP nameservers and caches the reply.

Now is it possible to find out the ISP nameserver without accessing the router? I was thinking about some `dig/nslookup` magic.

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/258151/how-do-i-check-what-dns-server-im-using-on-mac-os-x (although macOS-specific)

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
dig whoami.akamai.net
```

will tell you the IP of the ISP's nameserver. The akamai.net nameservers are running custom code, and respond to this name with the address of the client that made the DNS request.

Note that this may not tell you the address that your router is sending to. The nameserver may have multiple IPs -- often they're in clusters, and clients send to a cluster VIP, but the nameserver uses a real IP when forwarding to the authoritative server. The address returned by the above lookup will be the real IP, not the cluster VIP.

Comment: 1. is this still a legitimate approach (ie, is `whoami.akamai.net` still running this "custom code")?
2. can anyone offer suggestions on tracking down which service the resulting "real IP" might map to (eg: Cloudflare vs Quad9... if one is using such a name-brand upstream DNS server/service)?

Comment: I'm on Comcast, and it just returned the IP of a Comcast nameserver. So I think it still works.

Comment: Do a reverse lookup of the IP to find out what service it's part of.

Comment: Reverse lookups have me (thus far) seemingly running in circles: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnnyutahh/21087499990bb155416b3c6c5a9e5342/raw/ . The ultimate goal: I want to confirm I'm using Quad9 as my "default", upstream DNS. I can confirm that if I change the `server` setting in `dnsmasq.conf` (and restart the `dnsmasq` daemon) that the upstream DNS IP address (according to `whoami.akamai.net`) changes, so that helps. But determining who/what `res200.dfw.rrdns.pch.net` "belongs to" is the "tool in the toolbag" I'm looking to acquire.

Comment: `pch.net` is Packet Clearing House. Sounds like Quad9 isn't running their own DNS, they're outsourcing to PCH.

Comment: Thanks, and indeed this seems to be the case. I just found: https://support.quad9.net/hc/en-us/articles/4422044032781-Quad9-Network-Providers-WoodyNet-PCH-net-i3D-GSL-Networks-EdgeUno-Equinix-Metal. Also, this helps confirm that I'm on Quad9: https://on.quad9.net

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you set your computer to use the ISP's nameserver. DNS works in a chain. In the situation you described, your computer has no idea where your router is getting the IP for the  final destination - as far as it's concerned, your router is the final authority.

Your router thinks the same thing about your ISP's nameserver :)

Comment: I though there might be an option like: "Don't you worry about nothing, just give me the address you'd be asking and I'll handle the rest myself" :-)

Answer (score 0):

ipconfig /displaydns do it for you ?

When you're trying to avoid the router, is this part of a pen-test and you still have access to another web connection ? Thus an Nslookup query for your upsteams NS.

If you're pentesting, and assuming you already have the cursory set of port scan tools but want some more robust DNS tools, a good start is dns-grind, I use it in BackTrack and appreciate it's determination in squeezing out just as much info as ZoneTransfer !

http://pentestmonkey.net/tools/misc/dns-grind

Comment: That seems like an interesting tool, but I don't think it can achieve what I've asked for.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility that the DNS information is stored in an SNMP MIB variable.

`snmpwalk -v1 -c public (your ISP's device's IP address)`

(many assumptions are made regarding your operating system and installed software) if it works, might give you some leads.  It doesn't with mine, that I can see, but it does provide me with some mystery IP numbers which may or may not be resolving nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no universal and fool-proof way to do this.

I'm guessing you want a way to bypass the DNS Cache of the router though? So that you can just do an

> ipconfig /flushdns

To get fresh DNS results.

### How to bypass the DNS cache on your router

#### Option 1

- Manually hard-program a DNS router setting on your router DHCP server

Problem: Very few routers support this.

#### Option 2

- Give yourself a static DNS setting ie. Google's or OpenDNS'.

  > 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4 or 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220, 208.67.222.220, 208.67.220.222

#### Option 3

- Give yourself complete static address, router and DNS.

You can just copy the values provided by your router - but some bad routers will then hand out your address to another device and cause problems. If your subnet mask is /24 or 255.255.255.0, then you can simply change the last digit of your IP address to anything not within the range shown on the DHCP settings on the router. OR you can disable DHCP on your router completely - just note that no PC's on your network will get internet unless you put in static IP address details.

### Why?

Because some routers cause problems by caching your DNS, which will render some sites inaccessible or some commands on your computer - such as the flushdns commands, ineffective.

Answer (score -1):

Now, your question and the followups are just intriguing me,  but I don't get the impression you understand the nature of DNS and its determination to replicate consistent address/name resolution.

If you believe there is any value in getting name lookups from one server over another and of well known servers, not really, such as if you had to get the addresses of the StackExchange name servers and whether you query google's free DNS or your ISP's DNS, more than likely its gonna be the same info and probably just as fast whenever a change is made. Trying to differentiate between one free telephone directory assistance over another free telephone directory assistance when both have up the second info... doesn't really matter until you need really high speed and high volume lookups and bombarding anyone's DNS server unexpectedly will just get your source ip filtered, throttled down, whatever.

when I'm trying to mask my source, don't be afraid to admit it if that is your objective, time to consider at ToR client along with a ton of other stuff that can do the same.

Even further dude, and based on the fact you ain't being clear about what you're trying to do, but if I had to perform lookups while offline or didn't want to use DNS servers,then dig out a copy of ipofflineinfo.exe out of Nirsoft or find an archived version since I don't see it there at the moment cause it carries a pretty large but not comprehensive IP address DB encapsulated in the binary and can be configured to poll when connected or at intervals to update the way a submarine can surface before disappearing again.

then, you put those entries into your host files, don't ask me where that is cause it depends on which OS you don't to share you're using.

But finding the DNS server is possible if you want to use a sniffer, it is just as un-ncessary as wondering what city your capital one customer service is sitting in at the moment since no matter which DNS server you reach, you're gonna get the same answers until you start asking for inside domain info like a zone transfer, usually considered part of larger security probe and prelude to a network penetration,,, "hacking" that is a fun conversation we'd have on a different server instead of this one.

Your original question, the answer is yes, it can be done, in about four nslookupcommands that are inside every NSlookup help file, DNS is one of the oldest Inernet protocols and the older they are the less secure they are, you'll never be rid of spam cause the messaging protocols that enable it are too widely installed to replace effectively without creating new socioeconomic classes of email users.

So, share more details about what you're trying to accomplish, or get to Wikipedia cause this thread is becoming that basic. You seem like a decent guy, you contribute to the community and have a good rep, why you gotta be so protective so suddenly is just hard to help.

//Since you never came back with clarifying info, then I'll make some general presumptions and render the following nslookup magic to find other peoples DNS servers.  You have to be connected to make this work, trying to do so without is counterproductive. ReReading your original request makes me wonder if you were trying to hint you wanted to copy a DNS's server catalog of addresses which is a zone transer and is possible but not as likely as it used to be (considered a security weakness to transfer catalogs) or if you actually just wanted to copy the entire root zone of all DNS in the world, which isn't as impossible as most people think and hope but that a  whole nother discussion //

***This is for all the new DNS and NSLookup Curious in the world***

*C:\WINDOWS\system32>*nslookup  ***Starts an interactive NSLookup shell in Windows, most NSLOOKUP commands are ubiquitous across different operating systems***

Default Server:  resolver1.opendns.com ***shows my current DNS server name***
Address:  208.67.222.222 ***shows my current DNS server name***

> set d=2  ***Set debugLevel 2 / veryverbose and more than usual output / helpful for instructional reasons by displaying under the cover stuff***
>
> ### > server 8.8.8.8 ***Changing my preferred DNS server from opendns.com to Google's free DNS server also at 4.4.4.4***

Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

```
QUESTIONS:
    8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa, type = PTR, class = IN
ANSWERS:
->  8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa
    name = google-public-dns-a.google.com
    ttl = 79942 (22 hours 12 mins 22 secs)
```

---

Default Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

> **set type=ns** **Type is used to focus return data for a type of service/server listed in the queried domain, NS is the DNS server publicly listed as the DNS, MX is the external mail server which is to recieve email, etc**
>
> stackexchange.com **We've already set our DNS server to googles, set our type to return listed DNS Name Servers, if we enter any properly formatted domain, it is sent as a DNS "query" lookup request to 8.8.8.8**
>   Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
>   Address:  8.8.8.8

---

Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 3,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

```
QUESTIONS:
    stackexchange.com, type = NS, class = IN
ANSWERS:
->  stackexchange.com
    nameserver = ns2.serverfault.com
    ttl = 236 (3 mins 56 secs)
->  stackexchange.com
    nameserver = ns3.serverfault.com
    ttl = 236 (3 mins 56 secs)
->  stackexchange.com
    nameserver = ns1.serverfault.com
    ttl = 236 (3 mins 56 secs)
```

---

Non-authoritative answer:

stackexchange.com
        nameserver = ns2.serverfault.com
        ttl = 236 (3 mins 56 secs)
stackexchange.com
        nameserver = ns3.serverfault.com
        ttl = 236 (3 mins 56 secs)
stackexchange.com
        nameserver = ns1.serverfault.com
        ttl = 236 (3 mins 56 secs)

And the output is StackExchange's DNS servers are ns1, ns2 and ns3.serverfault.com
The term "lookup" is an official word when describing DNS servers. Those ns1-ns3 aren't necessarily the actual DNS servers inside the serverfault.com network but the address to send queries, more than likely they're IP filters and load balancers responsible for handling the query and behind the scenes without the users interaction, the "magic sauce" we take for granted just like turning on the faucet.

Not all DNS servers are "open", meaning trying to query Comcasts DNS servers or a corporations DNS server from outside the network will likely be prohibited to protect system resources and attacks.

DNS is one of the oldest IP protocols and usually the older the protocol, the likelihood it has a history of being attacked and a key mechanism of attack.  The original question hinted maybe you wanted to do this anonymously while getting current accurate info, I'm not criticizing or moralizing and whatever your reasons for remaining covert are yours. But know what I described will leave traces in the DNS servers log and any ISP in the chain between servers to the detail they log and retain those logs. It is possible to do this covertly but you'll have to share some context for an effective answer.

Google, keeps all traffic, all traffic never flushing it

Answer (score -1):

There's one solution I used. It break your request(dns tool only). https://dnsleaktest.com
IMO, it do these things.

1. First request some domain which are not exists.
2. Send these domain to server and the server will try to resolve these domain via public dns servers. If these domain exists in the dns server cache, then your dns request has been sent to that server.