# how can I tell which DNS server I'm using?

Tags: domain-name-system

If I have just changed the DNS server configured on my home router, for example to use 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 instead of my ISP's default DNS server, is there an easy way I can check whether my changes have correctly been applied, using dig or some other tool on MacOS?

Comment: If your client system using the router DNS server? Otherwise, changing that one won't change anything for your client system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your MacOS is using your router as the DNS server, it's the only server it uses. So no tool on your MacOS will show you any other server.

It's your router that uses 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 as a DNS server, not your MacOS, so to verify if your router really uses it, you need to capture DNS traffic **between your router and the Internet**.

If you have a router to which you can login via ssh and use a command line interface (for example based on OpenWRT), chances are you can run packet capture on the router itself (for example using `tcpdump`) and view the output. This would be the easiest way.

Otherwise, this will probably require plugging some traffic-intercepting device between **WAN port** (external port) of your router and your Internet connection (for example Ethernet port on your cable modem) - for example a switch with monitoring capability - then connecting a computer with packet capture software (like Wireshark) to this device.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to follow the solutions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/258151/how-do-i-check-what-dns-server-im-using-on-mac-os-x) ?

The commandline tool scutil returns the nameservers configured on your system :

```
scutil --dns | grep 'nameserver\[[0-9]*\]'
```

If it returns the homerouter IP, it should be good, since your homerouter will forward your DNS request to its configured DNS.

**In a home network configuration, you shouldn't worry much anyway.**

If you never set a static IP configuration on your client device, the DNS server should has been provided by your home router which means, if you changed the setting on your home router, the client device should follow along.

You should worry only in the following cases :

- you have set a host file (for static DNS query) on your system.
- you misconfigured the home router (if you did so, the house should be on fire by now since no one would have internet access).
- you tweaked your home network so hared that there are multiples routers/switch/vlan and whatever that the DNS server provided by your DHCP is a hidden device that no one know about.

If you really want to check if your DNS change propagate, you can try one or more of the following commands (I'm no expert on Macos and don't know the availability of these tools, i used ubuntu for testing), from the terminal:

```
dig whoami.akamai.net
```

It returns the server which answered your request

[dig on ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWw7o.png)

```
nslookup somewebsite.com
```

It returns also the information about the dns server :

[nslookup on ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaX3K.png)

The point is to make sure that your server which answered your question is no longer your ISP's. It may not be 1.1.1.1 nor 8.8.8.8 (depending on how dig and nslookup behave on your device), it may return the authoritative answer (which means the final server which give the request).

Comment: The scutil command does indeed just show the ip address of my router. The dig and nslookup commands do not include 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 anywhere in the output - they just show the authoritative answer, as you suggested. Really what I want is to be able to see the full resolution process and all the servers involved but maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: For the full resolution process, i can think of two (2) ways : 
- 1 you dump (with wireshark or tcpdump) the traffic of nslookup on port 53 (you will get the packet exchange flow between your device and your home router

- 2 with dig (this may be your solution) : 

dig +trace yourwebsite.com (which return the full process).

Comment: The 1.1.1.1 DNS server doesn't seem to feature in the output from dig +trace google.com. This is the output https://gist.github.com/ensconced/90c788fc48d45b783210dd44d67d93ab

Comment: `dig +trace`, by definition queries only authoritative nameservers